# Create pie chart with HighCharts in Django error - Blank page

Tags: django, highcharts

I'm trying to create a pie chart with highcharts with Django (with Mac Maverick), but I just get a blank page. Is there some error in my code below?
My data consists of a dictionary with 2 keys (body and id__count), the loop inside it works perfectly in body tag. But it's not working in script tag.

```
<script>
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

$(function () {
    var chart;       
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'categoryPieChart'
            },title: {
                text: 'Category'
            },tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ numberWithCommas(this.y.toFixed(2));
                }
            },exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: [
                        {% for cat in responses_pie %}
                        [
                            '{{ cat.body }}', 
                            {% if cat.id__count > 0 %}
                                {{ cat.id__count }}
                            {% else %}
                                0
                            {% endif %}
                        ],
                        {% endfor %}
                    ]
                }]
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the view source on Chrome in the script tag:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}

$(function () {
    var chart;       
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'categoryPieChart'
            },title: {
                text: 'Category'
            },tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ numberWithCommas(this.y.toFixed(2));
                }
            },exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: [

                        [
                            'apple', 

                                2

                        ],

                    ]
                }]
            });
        });
    });
});
```

And my view (views.py)

```
def piechart(request):
    responses_pie =  AnswerRadio.objects.values("body").annotate(Count("id"))
    return render(request, 'chart_code_v2.html', {'responses_pie': responses_pie})
```

Comment: Could you also post the generated javascript, i.e. what you see if you view source, and also post your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `});` at the end (one from `Highcharts.Chart({`, one from `$(document).ready(function() {`, one from `$(function () {` and one too much). This should be visible as a syntax error in your javascript console.

Also, calling `$(document).ready(fn)` is superfluous, because `$(fn)`, which you use on the function around it, is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(fn)`.

If you plan to support old Internet Explorer versions, you will also need to remove the last comma from your data, for example like this:

```
{% for cat in responses_pie %}    
[    
    '{{ cat.body }}',    
    {% if cat.id__count > 0 %}                                              
        {{ cat.id__count }}                                                 
    {% else %}                                                              
        0                                                                   
    {% endif %}                                                             
]{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}                                                                          
{% endfor %}
```

Generally, it is better to serialize data in the view via `json.dumps` and pass the string to the template, as it is less error prone. For example:

```
import json

def piechart(request):
    responses_pie =  AnswerRadio.objects.values("body").annotate(Count("id"))
    res = []
    for cat in responses_pie:
        res.append([
            cat.body,
            cat.id__count,
            # ... more stuff
        ])
    return render(request, 'chart_code_v2.html', {'responses_pie_json': json.dumps(res)})
```

then just use `data: {{ responses_pie_json|safe }}` in your template. Be aware that some Python objects (`datetime`, `Decimal`, ...) need some extra work for JSON serialization.

Comment: How can I serialize data in the view via json.dumps? Sorry, I'm new to django.

Comment: I've added an example above.

Comment: I'm trying to use data: {{ responses_pie_json|safe }}, but it's not wotking, it just shows a blank page. But when I use responses_pie_json|safe in body it works. What should I do?